# C++ error expression cannot be used as function

Tags: c++

How can I edit my formula for

```
weekday=(day+2(month)+3(month)/5+year+year/4-year/100+year/400)/7
```

so that I dont get an error message saying "expression cannot be used as a function"?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int date=0;
int month=0;
int day=0;
int year=0;
int leftover=0;
int weekday=0;

cout<<"Enter Date (ex.20140912) :";
cin>>date;

year=date/10000;
leftover=date%10000;
month=leftover/100;
day=date%100;
{
if (month==3)
    {cout<<"March "<< day<<", "<< year<<":";
        weekday=(day+2(month)+3(month)/5+year+year/4-year/100+year/400)/7;

            if (weekday==0)
                {cout<<"Saturday";
                }
            if (weekday==1)
                {cout<<"Sunday";
                }
            if (weekday==2)
                {cout<<"Monday";
                }
            if (weekday==3)
                {cout<<"Tuesday";
                }
            if (weekday==4)
                {cout<<"Wednesday";
                }
```

Comment: why did you declare the value for weekday twice?

Comment: { if (month==3) the opening bracket at the beginning of that line is malplaced.

Answer (score 3):

The code `2(month)` is function call syntax, as if `2` were a function... but it's not. Do you perhaps mean multiplication, such as `2 * month`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enter an operator (*) for multiplication:

```
weekday=(day+2*(month)+3*(month)/5+year+year/4-year/100+year/400)/7;
```

If the operator is missing c(++) interprets it as a function call, wherebthe function name is e.g. `2`.